# Gulp : Prepare dist folder and edit ini file

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I am trying to create a gulp task responsible to :
1. clean dist folder previouly created
2. Copy some folder inside new dist folder
3. Edit a ini file inside dist folder to update a key

```
var destination = './dist/test/v2';

// Copy ini file to dist folder
gulp.task('prepareDelivery', function () {
  gulp.src([source + '/ini/app_sample.ini']).pipe(gulp.dest(destination + '/ini/'));
});

// update version in ini file
gulp.task('prepareAppIni', ['prepareDelivery'], function () {
  var config = ini.parse(fs.readFileSync(destination + '/ini/app_sample.ini', 'utf-8'))
  config.DATA.version = '1.0'
  fs.writeFileSync(destination + '/ini/app.ini', ini.stringify(config, { section: 'section' }))
});

// default task
gulp.task('default', ['clean', 'prepareDelivery', 'prepareAppIni']);
```

I get this error :

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './dist/test/v2/ini/app_sample.ini'
```

I don't understand why, because i am waiting that prepareDelivery task is terminated before executing prepareAppIni task...

Could you help me ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I don't understand why, because i am waiting that prepareDelivery task is terminated before

That's not correct.
Your `default` task has multiple dependencies (`clean`, `prepareDelivery`, `prepareAppIni`), and all of them start at the same time.

Most likely you want want `prepareAppIni` to depend on `prepareDelivery`. Which, in turn, should depend on `clean` task. Having this implemented, `default` should depend only on `prepareAppIni`:

```
gulp.task('default', ['prepareAppIni']);
```

Also, you are missing `return` in `prepareDelivery`, so gulp doesn't know when it finishes. Should be

```
// Copy ini file to dist folder
gulp.task('prepareDelivery', function () {
  return gulp.src([source + '/ini/app_sample.ini']).pipe(gulp.dest(destination + '/ini/'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I try tu update my default task with your provided line but i still get the same error .. have you got another idea ?

Comment: @wawanopoulos I have just noticed you don't `return` in `prepareDelivery`, so gulp don't know when it finishes. Please try `return gulp.src([source + '/ini/app_sample.ini']) ...`